# Losing HTML format in Outlook (Spring Mail + FreeMarker)

Tags: html, outlook, freemarker

I have FreeMarker html code to send table via email (Outlook 2010):

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
    <tr class="tableHeader">
        <th>Report date</th>
        <th>Account Login</th>
        <th>View Id</th>
        <th>Utm marks</th>
        <th>Exception type</th>
        <th>Exception message</th>
    </tr>
    <#list marks as mark>
    <tr class="tableBody">
        <td>${mark.reportDate}</td>
        <td>${mark.accountLogin}</td>
        <td>${mark.accountViewId}</td>
        <td>${mark.utmMarks}</td>
        <td>${mark.exceptionType}</td>
        <td>${mark.exceptionMessage}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list>
</table>
```

First, I'm using `<th>` to make my `headers` bold and align by center. But it doesn't work. After this I tried to change width of one column:

```
<th width="50">Report date</th>
...
<td width="50">${mark.reportDate}</td>
```

But it's still don't work. Any changes applied to this table ignored by Outlook. I tested it with Gmail and it works like i want. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Some email clients completely ignore css styling. Outlook is one of them. It is always a good practice to **use html inline styling** when writing html email templates for maximum cross client compatibility.

```
<tr style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
   <th>Report date</th>
   <th>Account Login</th>
   <th>View Id</th>
   <th>Utm marks</th>
   <th>Exception type</th>
   <th>Exception message</th>
</tr>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
      <tr style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
          <th>Report date</th>
          <th>Account Login</th>
          <th>View Id</th>
          <th>Utm marks</th>
          <th>Exception type</th>
          <th>Exception message</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>${mark.reportDate}</td>
          <td>${mark.accountLogin}</td>
          <td>${mark.accountViewId}</td>
          <td>${mark.utmMarks}</td>
          <td>${mark.exceptionType}</td>
          <td>${mark.exceptionMessage}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```